# irb giving undefined methods for Twitter::Module

Tags: ruby, twitter, irb

Newbie attempting to experiment with Twitter api in irb (zsh shell on mountain lion) Using the twitter gem. I keep getting undefined method for Twitter::Module. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
irb(main):001:0> require "rubygems"
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require "twitter"
=> true
irb(main):003:0> puts Twitter.user("Suchitra_E").location
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for Twitter:Module
from (irb):3
from /Users/suchitraedussuriya-essl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0> Twitter.search('football', options = {})
NoMethodError: undefined method `search' for Twitter:Module
from (irb):4
from /Users/suchitraedussuriya-essl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Source code](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/user.rb) for user shows you that it is a `Class` within the Twitter `module`, hence should be instantiated first, i.e: `Twitter::User.new`.

Furthermore, you'll find examples on their [Github repo](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)